# "Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed" when calling a \Threaded class (pthreads) within a Symfony app

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads, threadpool, symfony4

I can not get PthreadsV3 to work with Symfony 4.1.4.

Running a simple proof of concept in a single PHP file works as expected but when moved to a Symfony `ContainerAwareCommand` I am greeted with the following error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not
>   allowed in [no active file]:0 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 {main}   thrown in [no active file] on line 0

I have a feeling that it has to do with the Symfony Container being copied and serialized in the \Threaded class. I tried to exclude the `Thread`, `Threaded` and `Worker` namespaces in the exclude list in services.yaml after a suggestion in the [bug report](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/28339) but that did not solve it.

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong. I am currently not sure if Symfony 4 with Pthreads is possible.

***The following code works from a single php file.***

```
<?php

$pool = new \Pool(4, TickerWorker::class, []);
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $pool->submit(new TickerTask($i));
}

while ($pool->collect()) ;

$pool->shutdown();

echo "Pool done\n";

class TickerWorker extends \Worker
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }
}

class TickerTask extends \Threaded
{
    protected $complete;
    private $i;

    public function __construct($i)
    {
        echo "$i start\n";
        $this->i = $i;
        $this->complete = false;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        sleep(rand(1, 3));
        echo "$this->i done\n";
        $this->complete = true;
    }

    public function isComplete()
    {
        return $this->complete;
    }
}
```

***This does not work and throws the exception***

```
<?php

namespace App\Command;

use App\Pthread\TickerTask;
use App\Pthread\TickerWorker;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
/**
 * Where App\Pthread\TickerWorker and App\Pthread\TickerTask 
 * are the classes as defined in the working example
 */
class CoconutTestCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'coconut:test';

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $pool = new \Pool(4, TickerWorker::class, []);
        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            $pool->submit(new TickerTask($i));
        }

        while ($pool->collect()) ;

        $pool->shutdown();
        echo "Pool done\n";
    }
}
```

Environment details:

- PHP 7.2.9 (cli) (built: Aug 15 2018 23:10:01) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
- Pthreads v3 built: 5/25/2018 8:44 AM
- Symfony version 4.1.4

Comment: I have the same issue but my symfony version 2.8 and php version is
PHP 7.2.9-dev (cli) (built: Sep  5 2018 14:13:58) ( ZTS )

when the task added into pool with submit method, it is throwing that message.

Answer (score 0):

Inside symfony(2.8) command, me neither make thread(3) work.
My php version:
PHP 7.2.9-dev (cli) (built: Sep  5 2018 14:13:58) ( ZTS )

But as an alternative solution:

- create a simple php file that has thread logic
- run that php file with using [popen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php)